# NULL in SQL need it Removed

Tags: sql, null

I would like to remove the "Null" in my week Column. Any help? I tried screenshots provided

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg0Lz.png)

[what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u44bx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try:

```
delete from [BKC_Menu_Analysis].[dbo].[FBBKCCompsWeekly] where week is NULL
```